# Why would you not use the php closing tag in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I am working with prestashop, which uses php. In their coding standards, they state not to use the closing `?>` php tag.  Why would you not use php closing tag, specifically in the Prestashop environment?

Stated [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Coding+Standards#CodingStandards-Tags) in coding standards, and [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module#Creatingafirstmodule-Creatingafirstmodule.1) in the tutorial for creating a custom module.

Comment: please search before asking - thanks.

Comment: Thank you I believe so. Perphaps someone can explain how it improves prestashop to omit the closing php tag.

Comment: The reason for Prestashop is not different from the reason for any other PHP application, so do have a look at Dagon's link.